# RcppEigen function fastLm : where's the variance-covariance matrix?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm using the `fastLm` function from the `RcppEigen` package

```
fit = fastLm(X, y, method)
```

which internally is doing something like

```
.Call("fastLm", X, y, method, PACKAGE = "RcppEigen")
```

In the documentation, it states that one of the values output by `fastLm` is `unsc`, the unscaled variance-covariance matrix. However, the function is not outputting this value. I tried `summary(fit)`, and it doesn't either.

Question 1: Is it just me, or has this not been implemented?

Question 2: Is there a way to extract/compute this value with the `RcppEigen` package?

I'm using `R 3.1.2 64-bit` and `RcppEigen_0.3.2.5.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fastLm()` implementation in RcppEigen by Doug follows the previous examples I wrote in RcppArmadillo and RcppGSL.

So *by design* it returns a vector of estimated coefficidents, a vector of estimated standard error of those -- this is the square root of the diagonal of that matrix -- and some other (mostly scalar) values. That is [documented in the help page for the function](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/man/fastLm.Rd)

If you want to alter it, you can look at the code: [header](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/src/fastLm.h), [source](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/src/fastLm.cpp).

Comment: thanks for your answer. In line 77 of the documentation, it says that `unsc` is a returned value, but looking at the source, that is not currently the case. Maybe the documentation should be updated. My C++ is not so good, maybe this is an opportunity to practice, just thought I should ask first...

Comment: Page 77 of what?   Anyway there is an [`XtX` object](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/src/fastLm.h#L68) you can access in the created [`lm` object](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/src/fastLm.cpp#L213).  This is however a highly non-trivial example.

Comment: line 77 of the help page that you linked to. The reason I'm asking about the vcov matrix is that I would like to replace `lm` for `fastLm` in some of my code, but it's not worth unless I have this as output.

Comment: Oh, right. That help page may need an update as you suggest. I'll try to get to that over the weekend.

Comment: That will be commited as pull request #22 in a moment (with some other changes).  Not sure when then it'll get to CRAN though.